# How to run ctags?

Tags: package-management, dpkg, executable

I've installed [exuberant-ctags](http://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/exuberant-ctags/) package, but when I run `ctags`, `etags` or `exuberant-ctags`, I always get *command not found*.

Where can I find executable file to run exuberant-ctags?

Comment: what is the version of your OS? and can you mention about how you installed the exuberant-ctags?

Comment: @VRU, OS is Ubuntu 12.10 and I used `apt-get` to install exuberant-ctags. I updated the question with this info.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The executable is named `ctags-exuberant`.

The answer could be found using `dpkg -L`, that shows a list of all files provided by a package. In your case you should see something like the following:

```
$ dpkg -L exuberant-ctags
/.
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/ctags-exuberant
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/exuberant-ctags
/usr/share/doc/exuberant-ctags/FAQ.gz
/usr/share/doc/exuberant-ctags/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/exuberant-ctags/copyright
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/ctags-exuberant.1.gz
```

Files in `/bin`, `/sbin`, `/usr/bin` and `/usr/sbin` are executables (i.e. commands).